# Copying Subversion commit files to a live website

Tags: svn

I'm trying to setup a test copy of my website on a server independent to the main one.

This server is hosted by nazwa.pl. I have the subversion server already setup there and I am able to make commits, updates etc.

My website runs from the "/" directory, and my repo is setup in "/.svnrepo/repo_name".

What I would like to do is to copy new files after every commit to a directory of a live website. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html I've found a solution.

All I had to do was to use a post-commit hook file, where I put the command mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

First order of business, get your repository out of that directory. Your repository database should not be exposed so readily to regular web visitors.

Updating a website managed by Subversion is such a common request that it's [addressed in the Subversion FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#website-auto-update). Another option not mentioned by the FAQ is using a [Continuous Delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery) solution.

Comment: Hi alroc, thank you for your answer!
Unfortunately I have no means to change the repository directory, as the instalation of svn lies on my hosting provider's side. But it's not an issue, as the '/' directory is password protected, and repo throws the "403 Forbidden" error.
I've tried the first solution you mentioned and it worked (as in running the script I provided), but I have no idea how to copy the files to the main directory or how to commit these changes made :/
I think I'll try the second one.